# Remove escape sequences from parsed HTML

Tags: python, html, escaping, mechanize

I'm using the Python `mechanize` module to submit a simple query to a website, then break down the returned elements to get the data I need. But I can't seem to correctly handle the escape sequences that get passed back. here's my code:

```
def stripEscape(string):    #credit goes to sarnold
    delete = ""
    i=1
    while (i<0x20):
        delete += chr(i)
        i += 1
    t = string.translate(None, delete)
    return t

def getHTML(metID):
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    response = br.open("http://urlgoeshere.com")

    br.form = list(br.forms())[0]
    br["PROMPT12"] = metID

    response = br.submit()
    htmlText = response.read()
    parseHTML(htmlText)

def parseHTML(htmlText):
    htmlText.index('table')
    arr = re.split(r'(</?\w{2}>)',htmlText)   # everything after background tag 
    logFile = open('Log.txt','wb')

    for ele in arr:
        ele = stripEscape(ele)
        if ele == '':
            arr.remove(ele)

    for ele in arr:
        logFile.write("ele: "+ele+'\n') 
        if re.match('/table', ele):
            logFile.write("END OF TABLE FOUND")
            logFile.write("\nele: "+ele+'\n')
            break
        # other element filters
```

The stripEscape function works just fine when I pass it arguments via interactive shell, but one of the array elements from the website is `\r\n</table>\r\n`, and this "escapes" my filters. It gets written to my log file like so:

```
ele: normal
ele: stuff
ele: 
</table>

ele: more
ele: normal
```

The closing table tag bypassing the filter causes all my other filters to go haywire. Is there a better way of handling escape sequences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ele element in first for loop is not saved to array.

```
for ele in arr:
    ele = stripEscape(ele)
    if ele == '':
        arr.remove(ele)
```

This part of code will only change `ele` element **NOT** the `arr`. `arr` will stay the same. So all escape sequences will **NOT** be deleted. You can test it by printing `arr` after that loop.

So what you need to do is to save it as a new array which then can be used by the next loop. It can be something like this:

```
for ele in arr:
    if ele != "":
        newArray.append(stripEscape(ele))


for ele in newArray:
    logFile.write("ele: "+ele+'\n') 
    if re.match('/table', ele):
        logFile.write("END OF TABLE FOUND")
        logFile.write("\nele: "+ele+'\n')
        break
```

Comment: Definitely a facepalm moment. Should have seen that.